# Alternative to wsgiref simple_server

Tags: python

I've got a program that I designed when I was first learning Python.  I'd still consider myself a beginner, but I'm a lot better than what I was at the time.

Anyway, I've got these lines:

```
s = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('', 8765, app)
s.handle_request()
```

and I have an error with it now.  I've been putting the site into an iframe in our website, but some of our clients have firewalls that don't like an iframe pointing to a straight IP address.

Now, I can't point a website to this.  [It won't point to a specific port](https://serverfault.com/questions/359171/domain-name-pointing-to-ip-address-with-specific-port).

Is there a simple way to change it so I can point my site to it?  Or am I going to have to rewrite it all?  I could do cgi, I guess.  Is there anything I could do instead?

Comment: You need to get under the umbrella of the actual webapp you are running. The technology you yourself are then using isn't really relevant (wsgiref is fine, alternatives could offer more features but don't change the underlying problem. So - what's the site running on? Details matter, e.g. a NGINX-based frontend with round-robin dispatch to apache-hosted PHP would offer different options than a pure apache-setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Almost all of my code stayed the same, except instead of delivering the page (variable 'app') with a simple server, I just printed it, after I'd printed the cgi html content-type line.  Also, throwing in that #!/usr/bin/python line.  Works perfectly.